# Why would executing a function in parallel significantly slowdown the program?

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a code using OpenMP, the serial time for my current input size is around 9 seconds, I have a code of the following form:

```
int main()
{
    /* do some stuff*/ 
    myfunction();
}

void myfunction()
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //it has some parameters but that is beyond the point I guess
        int rand = custom_random_generator();
        compute(rand);
    }
}
```

so here the random generator can be executed in parallel since there are no dependencies, and the same goes for the compute function so I was attempting to parallel this piece but all my attempts resulted in a failure, the first thought was to put these functions as task so they get executed in parallel but resulted in a slower result, here is what I did

```
void myfunction()
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp task 
        {
            //it has some parameters but that is beyond the point I guess
            int rand=custom_random_generator();
            compute(rand);
        }
    }
}
```

Result: 23 seconds, more than double the serial time

Putting task on `compute()` only resulted in the same

Even worse attempt:

```
void myfunction()
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        //it has some parameters but that is beyond the point I guess
        int rand=custom_random_generator();
        compute(rand);
    }
}
```

Result: 45 seconds

Theoretically speaking, why could this happen? I know that for anyone to tell my exact problem they would need a minimum reproducible example but my goal from the question is to understand the different theories that could explain my problem and apply them myself, why would parallelizing an "embarrassingly parallel" piece of code result in **way worse** performance?

Comment: Something else is causing all this overhead cannot only be the thread creation, I would suspect false sharing, cache invalidation and so on, how many cores do you have?

Comment: I have a macbook air 2019 with intel core i5 so I have 2 cores but run 4 threads in parallel as it supports hyperthreading @dreamcrash

Comment: Can you tell me the times with #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(1), then num_threads(2) ?

Comment: @dreamcrash in which configuration? I mentioned 2 solutions, I am not sure if you mean "#pragma omp parallel" for num_threads(1) or "#pragma omp parallel for"  with num_therads(1)

Comment: The second  one with  #pragma omp parallel for

Comment: I got 9 seconds for 1 thread and 28 seconds for 2, note that it is 45 seconds for 4 threads

Comment: Something is wrong in your code and with the currently example is impossible to tell

Comment: No problem, look for race conditions shared states this include external function calls

Comment: `custom_random_generator()` does not have any parameter and is supposed to return a random value. Thus, this means there is an *implicit state* (eg. global variable) and this state is likely *shared* between your threads. You could put your state thread-local to avoid race any conditions. Can you tell us more about that or at least precise this point? (not that race condition are not only important for performance here because the result may not actually be random due to that).

Comment: Your task code has no parallelism! (There is no parallel directive anywhere in the code). You may also want to look at papers on parallel random number generation, it is not a trivial task. (E.g. 
Parallel Random Numbers: As Easy as 1, 2, 3 - The Salmons http://www.thesalmons.org/john/random123/papers/random123sc11.pdf )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One theory could be the overhead that is associated with creating and maintaining multiple threads.

The advantges of parallel programming can only be seen when each iteration has to perform more complicated processor intensive tasks.

A simple for loop with some simple routine inside would not take advantage of it.

Comment: my random generator is pretty complex but my compute function just returns the result of a simple equation, I think I will try to only parallelize it then

Comment: task failed successfully! It improved the time to 18 seconds but it is still 2 times worse than the serial but I guess that confirms that task creating is creating overhead

Comment: Something else is causing all this overhead cannot only be the thread creation, I would suspect false sharing, cache invalidation and so on

Comment: @Sergio   great throwback, windows still has some gems though, [check the return  for winAPI successful function calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-).

Comment: @dreamcrash, I also think that that would be too much, but it's hard to tell. I'll maybe add that to my answer. When I saw the openmp tag I thought you'd show up ;)

Comment: :D in all fairness I think the problem is that OP example does not accurate represent the code where the parallelizations, hence one can only speculate